# Append multiple lines after a certain pattern to several JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, bash, shell, jq

I have several JSON files that look like this

```
{
"$schema": "someURL",
  "id": "someURL",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "copyright": {
      "id": "someURL",
      "type": "object",
      "description": "Setup for copyright link",
      "properties": {
        "translation": {
          "id": "someURL",
          "type": "string",
          "description": "someString"
        },
        "url": {
          "id": "someURL",
          "type": "string",
          "description": "someString"
        }
      }...
```

what I need to do is add a `removable` and `appendable` attribute to each item inside every instance of `properties` and set them to true. so the output should look like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "someURL",
      "id": "someURL",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "copyright": {
          "removable": true,
          "appendable": true,
          "id": "someURL",
          "type": "object",
          "description": "Setup for copyright link",
          "properties": {
            "translation": {
              "removable": true,
              "appendable": true,
              "id": "someURL",
              "type": "string",
              "description": "someString"
            },
            "url": {
              "removable": true,
              "appendable": true,
              "id": "someURL",
              "type": "string",
              "description": "someString"
            }
          }...
```

Is there a way to automate this? as in write a script that automatically adds these fields right below each item in properties?

Answer (score 0):

using NodeJS I would write something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let args = process.argv.map(val=>val));
let contents = fs.readFileSync(args[0]);

let obj = JSON.parse(contents);

const proc = (obj, append)=>{
    for (prop in obj)
    {
        let p = obj[prop];
        if (p.constructor!=Object)
            continue;
        if (append)
        {
            p.removable = true;
            p.appendable = true;
        }
        proc(p, prop=='properties');
    }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(proc(obj), null, 2));
```

And then in bash do:

```
find -name '*\.json' -exec 'node proc.js {} > {}.new'
```

I didn't test anything, everything is from my head, but for starting point should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to apply the update to all objects that have a key named "properties", wherever they occur, I'd be inclined to use `walk/1`. In any case, to make things clearer and maybe easier, it will be helpful to define a helper function that will apply the update if the input is of the right type:

```
def update(obj):
  if type == "object" and has("properties")
  then .properties |= with_entries( .value += obj )
  else .
  end;
```

Using `walk/1`, the solution is now trivial:

```
walk( update({removable: true, appendable: true}) )
```

#### Robustification

It might be prudent to change the "then" line above to:

```
then .properties |= 
  with_entries( if .value | type == "object"
                then .value += obj
                else . end)
```